# neutral element for "|" and "&" operations for django.db.models.Q objects?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

What is the neutral element for `django.db.models.Q` objects for `|` operation? I'd like to generate a filter with a function:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(myfunc(args)) where myfunc should give something like: "Q(foo) | Q(bar) | ... | False"
```

but I don't know what is `False` for `Q` objects. Similarly, I would need the neutral element for `&` operation (`True`)...

Here is an example of such a function:

```
# Models
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    myfield2 = models.CharField(max_length=30)


# Views
class MyView(views.View):
    model = MyModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        def myfunc(query_object_list, param):
            myfuncr = lambda l: ((myfuncr(l[1:]) | Q(**{ param: l[0] })) if l else Q(False)) # "Q(False)" would be the neutral element of operation "|" for Q objects
            return myfuncr(query_object_list)

        myq = Q(True) # "Q(True)" would be the neutral element of operation "&" for Q objects
        for param in self.request.GET:
            myq &= myfunc(self.request.GET.getlist(param, None), param)

        return MyModel.objects.filter(myq)


# Template
<a href='{% url myview %}?myfield1__iexact={{ myvar1 }}&myfield2__iexact={{ myvar2 }}'>foobar</a>
```

Comment: What is the filter you are trying to do?

Comment: neutral objects have no logic benefit in creating a query. downvoted.

Comment: neutral objects would permit the creation of a function that computes a dynamic generated filter (see my example)

Comment: Can't you just use `n-1` operators instead of `n`?

Comment: But I would have to treat separately the case n=0... Don't Q(matches everything) and Q(matches nothing) exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found the solution, which was in fact pretty simple... the "neutral element" for Q objects, which is the same for operations "|" and "&" is: "Q()"

I now have a dynamic filter which can match everything I want in my templates...

```
# Models
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    myfield2 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    myinteger3 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)



# Views
class MyView(views.View):
    model = MyModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        def myfunc(query_object_list, param):
            myfuncr = lambda l: ((myfuncr(l[1:]) | Q(**{ param: l[0] })) if l else Q()) # Q() is the neutral element of operation "|" for Q objects
            return myfuncr(query_object_list)

        myq = Q() # Q() is the neutral element of operation "&" for Q objects
        for param in self.request.GET:
            myq &= myfunc(self.request.GET.getlist(param, None), param)

        return MyModel.objects.filter(myq)


# Template
<a href='{% url myview %}?myfield1__iexact={{ myvar1 }}&myfield2__iexact={{ myvar2 }}&myinteger3__gte={{ myvar3 }}'>foobar</a>

<a href='{% url myview %}?myinteger3__gte={{ myvar4 }}'>{{ myvar4 }}</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Who cares.

```
myq = reduce(operator.and_, (myfunc(self.request.GET.getlist(param, None), param) for param in self.request.GET))
```

Comment: From where should I import "operator.and_"? Else, it seems a pretty elegant solution :-)

Comment: OK... very simple: "import operator". It solves the problem for the "&", but not for the "|" (defined in "myfunc")

Comment: That would be `operator.or_`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but I don't think the question actually makes sense in this context. `&` and `|` are not really boolean operators on `Q` objects: the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query_utils.py#L33) overrrides the `__and__` and `__or__` methods so that they combine their arguments into a tree, which is how Django represents queries internally before converting to SQL.

Comment: My final goal is to create a dynamic filter for using it from templates (hope it's easier to understand with my example)

Comment: No, not really. I still don't understand what a neutral object is in this circumstance, or why you keep insisting that this is a boolean operation.

Comment: I edited it one more time to show the benefit of this recursive generated filter. Is it still unclear? Sorry if "boolean operation" and "neutral object" are not the good words for describing that... I just want to be able to use MyModel.objects.filter(Q(Matches everything) & Q(filter1) & (Q(filter2) | Q(filter3) | Q(Matches nothing)))